# Nginx route '/admin/*' url to a backend app

Tags: nginx

I have a rails app and a front-end app written in VueJS, both on the same host. They are configured to use the same Nginx server. I can access my frontend app at IP 1.2.3.4 in the browser without problems, however I also have `/admin/*` routes in my rails app and now, when I access `1.2.3.4/admin` it obviously doesn't work because I am trying to access `/admin` page in my frontend app.

Now, is it possible to configure Nginx to route requests from `1.2.3.4/admin/` and all other requests like `/admin/posts` to my backend app?

This is my `nginx.conf` file.

```
http {

  passenger_root /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/passenger-5.3.5;
  passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby;

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  # Here is my rails app server config
  server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  bikeramp.local;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    root /home/deploy/bikeramp/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bikeramp.access.log;

    # Here's my VueJS app server config
  server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  bikeramp_front.local;

    location / {
        root   /home/jdomanski/bikeramp-front;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your backend app? where do you need to "point" the connection to?

Comment: My backend app is on the same Ubuntu server as the frontend app. I want to point all requests that match `/admin/...` to my backend app, so `/admin/login`, `/admin/posts` would go to my backend app.

Comment: But where does your backend app listens? A port in your server? A socket? A directory where it has it's root? I'll leave a generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http {

passenger_root /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/passenger-5.3.5;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

# Here is my rails app server config
server {
listen       3000 default_server; # default for port 3000
server_name  bikeramp.local 1.2.3.4;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

root /home/deploy/bikeramp/current/public;
passenger_enabled on;
rails_env production;
access_log /var/log/nginx/bikeramp.access.log;

# Here's my VueJS app server config

}
  server {
  listen       80 default_server; #default for port 80
  server_name  bikeramp_front.local;

  location /admin/ {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #in the backend sector, youlisten to port 3000, not 80, so you need to redirect the specific path you want there. This should kinda work.
  }
  location / {
      root   /home/jdomanski/bikeramp-front;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

}
```

The only server block that listens to port 80 (http connections, which is what you want), is the front end one. From there, you put a location on /admin/* , and redirect all that traffic to port 3000, where I see that your backend app server block listens. Is the code clean and clear enough? I can try to reformat it.

https://www.linode.com/docs/development/ror/ruby-on-rails-nginx-debian/

Comment: I have updated my question so that you know which server block is for which application.

Comment: You have your server blocks nested one inside the other, I think you prefer to separate them for a better debugging.. Editing my answer for a clearer view.

Comment: It's not nested, it was just wrong indentations here in the question. I have two separate server blocks in the config.

Comment: Oooh okay, well, I have put a solution, tell me if it works to you. (the location /admin/ on the frontend port 80 that proxies to backend port 3000).

Comment: This 'kinda' works - I can now access `/admin` page but it looks like the assets are broken (no styling) and if I put the username and password to sign in as admin I get `Page is not working' HTTP ERROR 422` error.

Comment: That's where I can't help you anymore, sorry, as I have no idea on ruby interactions with requests nor VueJS. If your requests lacks something you can ping me back and I'll try to set the right nginx configuration for you. Also, if it helps, set logs to nginx requests so you can debug better.

Comment: I checked my rails app logs and noticed `Invalid authenticity token` errors so this was my rails problem. I set upstream backend { server 127.0.0.1:3000; } and in server { ... proxy_pass http://backend; }, fixed the app issue and it works. Thank you for pointing me to the logs!